# On scroll, draw triangle from start, but it's not happening in this code

Tags: javascript, svg

Below is example code for drawing a triangle on scroll.
But I want to draw a triangle when the triangle section comes.

Give me a solution with JavaScript code.
How can I handle this problem?

```js
var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
var length = triangle.getTotalLength();

  triangle.style.strokeDasharray = length;

  triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

  function myFunction() {
  var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    var draw = length * scrollpercent;
     triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
  }
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }

  #mySVG {
    top: 15%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 210px;
    margin-left:-50px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>

  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>

  <svg id="mySVG">
    <path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" id="triangle" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
  </svg>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it: instead of using the `scroll` event I would use the `wheel` event on the svg element. But of coarse this may not be what you need.

When using `wheel` on the svg element you can scroll to the position of the svg element on page. Then you wheel over the svg. While over the svg element the page won't move yet the triangle will draw itself. Then you can continue scrolling the page.

```js
//the SVG element
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
// the total length of the path
let l = thePath.getTotalLength();
//the initial value for the stroke-dasharray
let dasharray = l;
//the initial value for the stroke-dashoffset
let dashoffset = l;
// styling the path
thePath.style.strokeDasharray = dasharray;
thePath.style.strokeDashoffset = dashoffset;


// on mouse wheel
svg.addEventListener("wheel",(e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (dashoffset > 0 && e.deltaY > 0 || 
        dashoffset < l && e.deltaY < 0) {
        dashoffset -= e.deltaY;
    }
   if(dashoffset < 0)dashoffset = 0;
   if(dashoffset > l)dashoffset = l;
    
    thePath.style.strokeDashoffset = dashoffset;
  }, false);
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }

  #mySVG {
    top: 15%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 210px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    border:1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
  <p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>

  <svg id="mySVG">
    <path id="thePath" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" id="triangle" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
  </svg>
```